# Converting from Base 16-8 to Base 2 without Functions nor Bitwise op in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment to make the Full Adder, it was chosen for us to practice the loops and conditinals in C.
So i did the easiest part of checking wether the number is in Base-2 and printing C-Out and Sum. But for Base-16 and Base-8 I couldn't figure out how to convert them to a smaller bases.
No advanced techniques are allowed, rules as follows:

- You are not allowed to use data structures such as arrays to store values for the conversion 
  operation.
- You are not allowed to use bitwise operators.
- You are not allowed to define your own functions.

I hope that you don't give me the full solution for this step, like only help me with converting one base to another, and i will try figuring out the rest of it by myself.

Comment: The usual bitwise operations regarding 2, 8 and 16 bit numbers are bitshift and bitwise or. Those can be replaced by multiplication/division by multiples of 2, and addition (respectively).

Comment: *You are not allowed to define your own functions* - that's the stupidest constraint I've ever seen. The others are not very bright too.

Comment: Cancel the class and request a refund.  Or contact the administration and demand they find a competent instructor.

Comment: "So i did the easiest part of checking wether the number is in Base-2 and printing C-Out and Sum" - that is not shown.  What was the specific trouble with "couldn't figure out how to convert them to a smaller bases."

Comment: @chux you are supposed to get three inputs base-2,8,16
i wrote the part of base 2 and still debugging it's errors, and couldn't think of a way to reach base 2 from 8 and 16 becuase i was so bad in the first cours that introduces this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way: you must be familiar with base 10, or decimal numbers. You use them every day. So how do they work? First, the number of symbols to represent them is the base number, 10. This is why, as you are counting the numbers, whenever you get to a power of 10, you need to increase the number of symbols used to represent the number. What you are asked to do here is kind of the reverse of that process. If you had to write down the digits of a number in base 10 without being allowed to see the number, how would you do it? I will give you the first step: you can get the least significant digit by diving the number by 10 and taking the remainder. This will give you the number of times you had to change the symbol used since the last time you had to increase the number of symbols used.

Comment: ill take a numbe%2, then i divide the same number/2, make it integer,and keep looping on this
i guess this is from base-10 --> base-2
and from base 16-8 this will be the num%10 num/10 to reach it to base 10

Comment: or even from base-16,8 i can get the modulo and divide?

Comment: The base that the number is currently in does not matter. And you divide by the base you want to write the number in. Say you want to write 6 in base 4. You would divide 6/4 which gives you 1 with remainder 2. So you know the least significant digit of the answer is 2. Then you keep dividing and taking the remainder.

Comment: thanq guys, both of you, u helped me writing my code for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do num%2 you will get the right most bit (LSBit)  -- depending on how you want to return the bit pattern (string etc) -- save this bit.

If you divide by two then you will lose the right most bit (LSBit) .. keep doing this in a loop until the number becomes zero.